# Prefill form with data in Symfony2, shorter way

Tags: forms, symfony, symfony-forms

I have form that can be used on front page and search page. Users can fill it on both pages, but if it is filled on front page it has to show filled data on the search page. to achieve this I'm forwarding the data, and using syntax similar to this.

```
$form->get('field')->setData($form_data['field']);
```

Everything works fine, except the form has a lot of fields and I was wondering if there is a shorter way to achieve the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this?

```
$form_data['return_box'] = (boolean)$form_data['return_box'];
$form->setData($form_data);
```

Comment: That could be the solution. But I have return_box field which is of CheckBox type and it's giving me `Unable to transform value for property path "[return_box]": Expected a Boolean.`

Comment: where did `return_box` come from, and you have `$form_datap`, shouldn't that instead be `$form_data`?